# find the second linearly independent solution to the equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the second linearly independent solution to the equation

$\displaystyle 2xy''+(5-2x)y'+\frac{y}{x}=0$

using the series method at the point $x=0$.

I try to solve with the following 
We need to find also y ,  y’ , y’’.

y=∑_(n=0)^∞▒〖c_n x^n 〗  ,y^'=∑_(n=1)^∞▒〖c_n nx^(n-1) 〗       ,     y^''=∑_(n=2)^∞▒〖c_n n(n-1)x^(n-2) 〗

We make the usual substitution of the power series. This results in the equation

2∑_(n=2)^∞▒〖c_n n(n-1)x^(n-1) 〗+5∑_(n=1)^∞▒〖c_n nx^(n-1) 〗-2∑_(n=1)^∞▒〖c_n nx^n 〗+∑_(n=0)^∞▒〖c_n x^(n-1) 〗=0
We can start the second sum at n = 0 without changing anything else. To make
each term include x^n in its general term, we shift the index of summation in the first
sum by +1 (replace n with n + 1)

2∑*(n=1)^∞▒〖c*(n+1) n(n+1) x^n 〗+5∑*(n=0)^∞▒〖c*(n+1) (n+1) x^n 〗-2∑_(n=1)^∞▒〖c_n nx^n 〗+∑*(n=1)^∞▒〖c*(n+1) x^n 〗=0

When n =1,      4c_2+10c_2-2c_1+c_2=0  ,          15c_2-2c_1=0   ,    c_2=(2c_1)/15 
〖2c〗*(n+1) n(n+1)+5c*(n+1) (n+1)-2c_n n+c_(n+1)=0

c_(n+1) (2n(n+1)+5(n+1)+1)-2c_n n=0   ,      c_(n+1)=(2c_n n)/(2n(n+1)+5(n+1)+1)

I'm stuck here what next step .

Comment: You now have something of the form $\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty} b_nx^n = 0$. So you should now make sure each of the $b_i$ is 0.

Comment: First off you need to shift the index so that you have terms of the form $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nx^n$$

Comment: Your question was edited twice and now you undid all the changes (why?). Please edit the question again to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the series of $\sum_0^\infty c_n x^n \,$ not solve the equation.

Hint:

$x^2y''-(x^2-\frac{5}{2}x)y'+\frac{y}{2}=0,\,\Rightarrow \color{red}{y= \sum_0^{\infty}c_nx^{n+\rho}},\,y' = \sum_0^{\infty}(n+\rho)c_nx^{n+\rho-1},\,y'' = \sum_0^{\infty}(n+\rho)(n+\rho-1)c_nx^{n+\rho-2}$

$x^2\sum_0^{\infty}(n+\rho)(n+\rho-1)c_nx^{n+\rho-2}-x^2\sum_0^{\infty}(n+\rho)c_nx^{n+\rho-1}+\frac{5}{2}x\sum_0^{\infty}(n+\rho)c_nx^{n+\rho-1}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_0^{\infty}c_nx^{n+\rho}=0$

$\sum_0^{\infty}(n+\rho)(n+\rho-1)c_nx^{n+\rho}-\sum_0^{\infty}(n+\rho)c_nx^{n+\rho+1}+\frac{5}{2}\sum_0^{\infty}(n+\rho)c_nx^{n+\rho}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_0^{\infty}c_nx^{n+\rho}=0$

Determine $ \rho:\,\, n=0\,\,\Rightarrow \rho(\rho-1)c_0x^{\rho}+\frac{5}{2}\rho c_0 x^{\rho}+\frac{1}{2}c_0x^{\rho}=\frac{1}{2}c_0x^{\rho}(2\rho^2+3\rho+1)=0$

$\Rightarrow 2\rho^2+3\rho+1=0 \Rightarrow \rho_{1}=-1,\rho_{2}=-\frac{1}{2};\,\,c_0 = $any constant

First solving equations by substitution series $y= \sum_1^{\infty}c_nx^{n-1},$
second solving by substitution $y= \sum_1^{\infty}c_nx^{n-\frac{1}{2}}.$